# Separate click event for first three td and last td not working in Dom change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having four column in my table. When we click one of the first three td that will do one operation and when we click last td that will do other kind of operation.
I did like this

```
$('#items_list tr td').not('#items_list tr td:last-child').click(function() {
  // Do  something
}

$("#items_list tr td:last-child").click(function() {
  // Do something
}
```

But those not working when Dom change. I try to use .live(), but the disadvantage of li is
Chaining methods is not supported. Any one can guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to add events to every cell on the table. One event handler at the table tbody level can handle it.

```
jQuery("#foo tbody").on("click", function (evt) {
   var elem = jQuery( evt.srcElement || evt.target );
    if (elem.is("td:last-child")) {
        alert("last child");
    } else {
        alert("not last child");
    }       
});
```

You might have to add code to the elem to look for the closest td if you have elements inside of the td.

```
if (!elem.is("td")) {
    elem = elem.closest("td");
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yBmVx/)

Comment: Correct since 1.6.4 does not have `on`. Just change the `on` to `bind` or just use `click(function{...})`.

Comment: Click will work for normal table(static table) but I want to work this also for DOM change (Through ajax call i am introducing table in page). I wil try bind....

Comment: You are replacing the whole table? Than use `live("click", function(){...})`. I thought you were just adding rows to the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#items_list tr td").last().click(function(){ });
```

Comment: This will work in normal table but i want to work in DOM change